# Update data to serializer when creating object with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My models.py look like this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = model.TextField(max_length=500)

class Jira(models.Model):
    jira_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    activity = model.ForeignKey(Activity, null=True on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

One activity can have multiple Jira tickets associated with it.Hence I am using a foreign key to denote one to many relationship.

My serializer to create a new activity is as follows:

```
class ActivityCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    jira_ticket = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

My view is as follows:

```
class ActivtyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ActiityCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           #jira_ticket = make call to jira and get a valid ticket number
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

As is evident, while a new Activity is created, an external API call needs to go out to the Jira ticketing system to create a new jira_ticket. This is happening successfully and I am getting back a jira_ticket number.
My question is two fold:

1. How do i save the Jira ticket in the DB since it is not part of the serializer and is obtained only once the request is made from an external API call ?
2. How do i add the jira ticket number to the serializer output since serializer.data is immutable and i am not able to append the jira_ticket to the response dict ?

Comment: Do you want to make client wait until you get ticket number from Jira ?

Comment: Yes..the ticket number should be in the serializer output..so yes..the client will have to wait..

Answer (score 0):

In the view after calling serializer.save() call the api for jira ticket and use that to store the jira ticket object with the activity object returned from serializer.save() method. You would also need to update the response to include the jira ticket data, the read only field is not required as the view will update the response data. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you show me some code..how does the view update the response data since serializer.data is immutable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the presave hook `perform_create()` of drf, something like this.

```
class ActivtyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer(jira_number=get_jira_ticket_number(serializer.data))
        serializer.save()
```

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/ (Search `perform_create`)

But I guess, calling 3rd party api in your request-response cycle is not a good practice. What will happen if something goes wrong will fetching ticket_number from jira ?

I would have returned whatever data we're having and trigger a background task to fetch ticket_number from jira and update the saved object with same. Client should keep polling for jira ticket_number. Or something like this.

Comment: Do I need to call perform_create from inside the create method ? Also how do I now update the serializer output ?

Comment: No, instead of `create()` method you need to override `perform_create()`

Comment: ..just to understand..what is the exact difference between the create and perform_create method ?

Comment: `create()` will handle create functionality (POST request), whereas `perform_create()` is a save hook. Check source code for more details.